# Recursive permutations of size k with no same elements next to each other

Tags: python, recursion

This is my first question, so please pardon my formatting. I am basically trying to create permutations with repetitions of size k with no repeating elements next to each other.
So, i have a list like 1,2,3,4 and a k value.
For example, by taking 1,2,3,4 and k=4,
we would get a list of all the possible permutations that have size k and no two same consecutive items, as such:
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,2
1,2,3,1
..and the list goes on
I can do basic permutations recursively, but I’ve been struggling with this for a while. I don’t want to import any libraries as I think it could be done without it, and I would like to append all the combinations in a list. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So, do you need to enumerate all such permutations, or randomly sample one of them? If you're sampling, you'll need at least a random number generator from `random`, so it could not be done strictly without libraries.

Answer (score 3):

To generate all permutations, you can pass down the current partial permutation and add every item in turn before calling the recursion to add another position (skipping the repeated item) :

```
def perm(A,k,p=[]):
    if not k:                          # size reached
        yield p 
        return          
    for n in A:                        # combine every item
        if p and n == p[-1]: continue  # except the repeated one
        yield from perm(A,k-1,p+[n])
```

Output:

```
# place in a list:

permList = list(perm([1,2,3,4],4))

# or access sequentially without storing:

for i,p in enumerate(perm([1,2,3,4],4)): print(i,p)

0 [1, 2, 1, 2]
1 [1, 2, 1, 3]
2 [1, 2, 1, 4]
3 [1, 2, 3, 1]
4 [1, 2, 3, 2]
5 [1, 2, 3, 4]
6 [1, 2, 4, 1]
7 [1, 2, 4, 2]
8 [1, 2, 4, 3]
9 [1, 3, 1, 2]
10 [1, 3, 1, 3]
11 [1, 3, 1, 4]
12 [1, 3, 2, 1]
13 [1, 3, 2, 3]
14 [1, 3, 2, 4]
15 [1, 3, 4, 1]
16 [1, 3, 4, 2]
17 [1, 3, 4, 3]
18 [1, 4, 1, 2]
19 [1, 4, 1, 3]
20 [1, 4, 1, 4]
21 [1, 4, 2, 1]
22 [1, 4, 2, 3]
23 [1, 4, 2, 4]
24 [1, 4, 3, 1]
25 [1, 4, 3, 2]
26 [1, 4, 3, 4]
27 [2, 1, 2, 1]
28 [2, 1, 2, 3]
29 [2, 1, 2, 4]
30 [2, 1, 3, 1]
31 [2, 1, 3, 2]
32 [2, 1, 3, 4]
33 [2, 1, 4, 1]
34 [2, 1, 4, 2]
35 [2, 1, 4, 3]
36 [2, 3, 1, 2]
37 [2, 3, 1, 3]
38 [2, 3, 1, 4]
39 [2, 3, 2, 1]
40 [2, 3, 2, 3]
41 [2, 3, 2, 4]
42 [2, 3, 4, 1]
43 [2, 3, 4, 2]
44 [2, 3, 4, 3]
45 [2, 4, 1, 2]
46 [2, 4, 1, 3]
47 [2, 4, 1, 4]
48 [2, 4, 2, 1]
49 [2, 4, 2, 3]
50 [2, 4, 2, 4]
51 [2, 4, 3, 1]
52 [2, 4, 3, 2]
53 [2, 4, 3, 4]
54 [3, 1, 2, 1]
55 [3, 1, 2, 3]
56 [3, 1, 2, 4]
57 [3, 1, 3, 1]
58 [3, 1, 3, 2]
59 [3, 1, 3, 4]
60 [3, 1, 4, 1]
61 [3, 1, 4, 2]
62 [3, 1, 4, 3]
63 [3, 2, 1, 2]
64 [3, 2, 1, 3]
65 [3, 2, 1, 4]
66 [3, 2, 3, 1]
67 [3, 2, 3, 2]
68 [3, 2, 3, 4]
69 [3, 2, 4, 1]
70 [3, 2, 4, 2]
71 [3, 2, 4, 3]
72 [3, 4, 1, 2]
73 [3, 4, 1, 3]
74 [3, 4, 1, 4]
75 [3, 4, 2, 1]
76 [3, 4, 2, 3]
77 [3, 4, 2, 4]
78 [3, 4, 3, 1]
79 [3, 4, 3, 2]
80 [3, 4, 3, 4]
81 [4, 1, 2, 1]
82 [4, 1, 2, 3]
83 [4, 1, 2, 4]
84 [4, 1, 3, 1]
85 [4, 1, 3, 2]
86 [4, 1, 3, 4]
87 [4, 1, 4, 1]
88 [4, 1, 4, 2]
89 [4, 1, 4, 3]
90 [4, 2, 1, 2]
91 [4, 2, 1, 3]
92 [4, 2, 1, 4]
93 [4, 2, 3, 1]
94 [4, 2, 3, 2]
95 [4, 2, 3, 4]
96 [4, 2, 4, 1]
97 [4, 2, 4, 2]
98 [4, 2, 4, 3]
99 [4, 3, 1, 2]
100 [4, 3, 1, 3]
101 [4, 3, 1, 4]
102 [4, 3, 2, 1]
103 [4, 3, 2, 3]
104 [4, 3, 2, 4]
105 [4, 3, 4, 1]
106 [4, 3, 4, 2]
107 [4, 3, 4, 3]
```

The function is a generator which allows you to get the permutations sequentially without having to store them all in a list (which could easily become too large and take a long time to generate).

If you want to manipulate the permutations as if you had a list but without generating the actual list, you can make a function that will give you then Nth permutation in a "virtual" list:

```
def permCount(A,k): return len(A)*(len(A)-1)**(k-1)
def permAtIndex(A,k,i):
    p = [len(A)]                 # positions of elements
    c = (len(A)-1)**(k-1)        # chunk of sub-permutations
    for _ in range(k):           # for required size
        j,i = divmod(i,c)        # j is index at position
        c //= len(A)-1           # next chunk size
        p.append(j+(j>=p[-1]))   # adjust index for non-repeat
    return [A[j] for j in p[1:]] # build permutation from indexes
```

This will give you the size of the permutation "list" and allow you to get a permutation at a given index (which you can select randomly if needed):

```
permCount([1,2,3,4],4)       # 108
permAtIndex([1,2,3,4],4,84)  # [4, 1, 3, 1]

permCount(range(15),10)                # 309915701760
permAtIndex(range(15),10,123456789101) # [5, 14, 9, 2, 5, 10, 7, 3, 0, 10]
```

**[EDIT]** returning a list directly:

```
def perm(A,k,p=[]):
    if not k:                          # size reached
        return [p]               
    result = []
    for n in A:                        # combine every item
        if p and n == p[-1]: continue  # except the repeated one
        result += perm(A,k-1,p+[n])
    return result
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually just need to get all the permutations in a list :)

Comment: Would there be any way to use a list instead of a generator?

Comment: Yes (although you can use the generator to create the list). I'll add an example.

Answer (score 0):

**Returning just a single permutation:**

I know, you didn't want to use a library, but you need to have some sort of randomness:

```
from random import sample 
k = 4
l = [i for i in range(k)]
sample(l, k)
```

and this would be recursive:

```
from random import randint

def recursvie_sample(l, k):
    if k == 1:
        return l
    else:
        return [l.pop(randint(0, k - 1))] + recursvie_sample(l, k - 1)

k = 4
l = [i for i in range(k)]
recursvie_sample(l.copy(), k)
```

Note: copying list `l` as input value for the `recursive_sample` keeps`l` unaltered through the function call, and you could still use it afterwards...

### EDIT

**Listing all permutations without any digit appearing several times**

```
def perm(l1, l2 = []):
    if not l1:
        result.append(l2)
    else:
        for i in range(len(l1)):
            l1_copy = l1.copy()
            l2_copy = l2.copy()
            l2_copy.append(l1_copy.pop(i))
            perm(l1_copy, l2_copy)

result = []
initList = [i for i in range(4)]
perm(initList)
print(result)
```

Comment: Can you explain how this addresses the constraint of not having two consecutive elements in the sample being the same?

Comment: I must have expressed myself wrong! I meant all the permutations of size k with no repeating elements. So, we would get multiple outputs, not just one.

Comment: @IvanLeongito But then your example `1,3,2,3` is not a valid example. Please edit the question to clarify!

Comment: Edited! Note that I need to apply the function on a given list and a given k, so the i for in range(4) would not work in this case.

Comment: Ah ok, you wanted to have items with duplications of entries/digits as well. Yeah then, Alain‘s solution is of course correct…